# Object vs Object

Tags: javascript

```js
function Person(idn, dep, nam, age, gen, aut) {
    this.idn = idn; //IDNumber
    this.dep = dep; //Department
    this.nam = nam; //Name
    this.age = age; //Age
    this.gen = gen; //Gender
    this.aut = aut;
  } //Auto

function Car(make, modl, year, lice, colo, mile, ownr) {
    this.make = make; //MakeOfTheCar
    this.modl = modl; //ModelOfTheCar
    this.year = year; //Year
    this.lice = lice; //Licence
    this.colo = colo; //ColorOfTheCar
    this.mile = mile; //Mileage
    this.ownr = ownr;
  } //Owner

var p01 = new Person(3475, 1, 'Rand,McKinnon', 33, 'M', c01);
var p02 = new Person(7608, 2, 'Ken,Jones', 39, 'M', c02);
var p03 = new Person(1957, 3, 'Vladi,Orlov', 58, 'M', c03);

var c01 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon,TSi', 1993, 'BP456H46', 'red', 201, p01);
var c02 = new Car('Nissan', '300,ZX', 'J001', 1992, 'blue', 244, p02);
var c03 = new Car('Toyota', 'Avalon,XLS', '6HPR64W', 2000, 'black', 118, p03);

document.write('Car:c03.make=', c03.make, '|', c03.colo, '|', c03.ownr.nam, '<br>');
document.write('Person:p03.idn=', p03.idn, '|', p03.nam, '|', p03.gen, '|', p03.aut, '<br>');
```

> Last parameter (p03.aut): undefined

Need your help to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Your `c` variables are not initialized when you create your `Person` objects.

Comment: Well none of the `Car` objects exist when you try to pass them to `new Person()`, so `undefined` should be expected.

Comment: ouch if  someone owns 2 cars!

Answer (score 3):

At the time you execute this line of code:

```
var p03 = new Person(1957, 3, 'Vladi,Orlov', 58, 'M', c03);
```

`c03` does not yet have a value.  So, you're passing an `undefined` value there and that is what is stored in `p03.aut`.  When you later retrieve that value, it is retrieves that `undefined` value that you previously put there.

Since you have a chicken and egg problem (both objects can't both have their constructors called while referencing each other since one of them has to be created first), you will have set one of those arguments on the object after both have been constructed (e.g. not in the constructor).

For example you could do this:

```
var p01 = new Person(3475, 1, 'Rand,McKinnon', 33, 'M');
var p02 = new Person(7608, 2, 'Ken,Jones', 39, 'M');
var p03 = new Person(1957, 3, 'Vladi,Orlov', 58, 'M');

var c01 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon,TSi', 1993, 'BP456H46', 'red', 201, p01);
var c02 = new Car('Nissan', '300,ZX', 'J001', 1992, 'blue', 244, p02);
var c03 = new Car('Toyota', 'Avalon,XLS', '6HPR64W', 2000, 'black', 118, p03);

p01.aut = c01;
p02.aut = c02;
p03.aut = c03;

document.write('Car:c03.make=', c03.make, '|', c03.colo, '|', c03.ownr.nam, '<br>');
document.write('Person:p03.idn=', p03.idn, '|', p03.nam, '|', p03.gen, '|', p03.aut, '<br>');
```